# upload many images with they label

Tags: php, forms

I need to upload 5 images at ones with they labels I have made this before to upload many images at one it works fine but I need to have an label for each image how this can be done

take a look at my code.

this is the HTML code

```
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <?php if(isset($_GET['msg'])){$msg=$_GET['msg']; echo $msg;} ?>
  <span style="font-weight: bold; color: #F00;">*ملحوظة </span>الصورة الأولي التي سترفع ستكون صورة المشروع الأساسية نرجوا أختيارها بعناية

  <p><label for="img1">صورة 1</label>
  <input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField1" />
  <input type="text" name="Limage[]" id="Limage1" placeholder="Add label">
  </p>

  <p><label for="img2">صورة 2</label>
  <input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField2" />
  <input type="text" name="Limage[]" id="Limage2" placeholder="Add label">
  </p>

  <p><label for="img3">صورة 3</label>
  <input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField3" />
  <input type="text" name="Limage[]" id="Limage3" placeholder="Add label">
  </p>

  <p><label for="img4">صورة 4</label>
  <input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField4" />
  <input type="text" name="Limage[]" id="Limage4" placeholder="Add label">
  </p>

  <p><label for="img5">صورة 5</label>
  <input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField5" />
  <input type="text" name="Limage[]" id="Limage5" placeholder="Add label">
  </p>

 <p><input type="submit" name="submitCon" id="submitCon" value="Upload More Images">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="I am Finished"></p>
</form>
```

and this is my php for uploading the images

```
    if(isset($_POST['submitCon'])){
$target = '../images/Projects/';
    $num=1;
    $projectID=$p;
    foreach ($_FILES["img"]["error"] as $key => $error)
    {
        if ($error==UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
        {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $name = $_FILES["img"]["name"][$key];
            $label=$_POST['Limage'];
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$target/$name");

            $putData = "INSERT INTO projects_images (id, label, image, image_id)VALUE('', '$name', '$label', '$projectID')";
            $result = $db->query($putData)or die($db->error);
            if($result){
                header('Location:index.php?cid=9&proid=8&p='.$p.'&msg=Images has been uploaded successfully, Need to upload more, after you finish uploading plans save and edit the project');
                }else{
                echo"Error";
            }
        }
    } 
}
?>
```

I edit the code and now I am getting the name of the image instead of the label?? 
any help please

Comment: Do you have a location in your database for the label? You can change the label name from Limage1 (2 3 4 5) to Limage[] and it will be an array. Then you can use that array to in your insert query.

Comment: Yes I have and I just did what you said now please can you guide me to how can I use the array in my insert query `$putData = "INSERT INTO projects_images (id, label, image, image_id)VALUE('', '??', '$name', '$projectID')";` what should I post to my database

Comment: @seveneves see my edit on the question

Comment: The value for the label would be $_POST['Limage'][$key] in your query. If the $key is being incremented every time in your loop.

Comment: @seveneves can you please show this on my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the label based off the key that you are already using in your foreach. You're already doing this for the rest of the file information.

`$label=$_POST['Limage'][$key];`

Also you're insert is backwards:

```
$putData = "INSERT INTO projects_images (id, label, image, image_id)VALUE('', '$name', '$label', '$projectID')";
```

should be:

```
$putData = "INSERT INTO projects_images (id, label, image, image_id)VALUE('', '$label', '$name', '$projectID')";
```

Just make sure you are properly escaping your data before you put it into the database.

Comment: Thanks very much @Samuel Cook I didn't see my mistake...thanks again very much